# AirDrop stopped working on all my Macs all at once

Tags: airdrop

I was transferring files between my 3 different Macs and one iPhone and then suddenly none of them can find any of the others.

Discovery is set to "everyone".

AirDrop doesn't even do the radar thing where it tries to find other nearby devices.

If it had just been one device, it wouldn't be so strange, but none of them work...all simultaneously. What could have caused this?

Resetting Bluetooth or WiFi don't work. Restarting doesn't work.

Comment: Have you checked your Apple ID? Changed the password?

Comment: Did you restart your router in your troubleshooting routine?